# xcode add a button to my storyboard navigation item?

Tags: xcode

I have this in my storyboard:

[image]

I would like to add a new button next to the 'Community Button'

but when I try to add a new Button Bar Item, it just replaces the button that is already there. How would I do this?

[image]

and when I try to add a 'Button' it does not let me add it to the Bar Button Item - Item:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do this using the storyboard but it can be done in the code as follows.

In the viewDidLoad method of completionVC do the following:

1. create UIBarButtonItem for community
2. create UIBarButtonItem for add
3. Add the buttons to the navigationItem using:

   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithItems:community, add, nil];